# Stuck at Hibernate "create table HT_"

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, firebird

I have to develop a WAR-Application in Netbeans. As a Webserver I use the built-in Jetty to test the WAR, because the release version should also use Jetty.
In Netbeans I have a setup to redeploy the WAR after saving a file.

And there I have the problem that after a redeploy (the first deploy works fine) at connecting to the Firebird database again, the Application is stopping at the first output of:

```
Hibernate: create table HT_mytable (myid numeric(18,0) not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36))
```

This my code for creating the EntityManager

```
protected EntityManager createEntityManager(String databaseName) {
    String user = this.settingsService.getValue("user", "database");
    String password = this.settingsService.getValue("password", "database");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", this.createUrlForDatabase(databaseName));
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", user);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");

    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNITNAME_PREFIX + databaseName, properties);
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    } catch(PersistenceException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EntityService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you get an exception, or does it just halt?

Comment: it just halts at this output.

Comment: What do you mean by "redeploy"? Does the table already exist when the redeploy happens?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann The `HT_` tables are automatically created by Hibernate for - IIRC - some type of ID generating. In most databases these are global temporary tables. By the sound of it, there is a problem with wait transaction.

Comment: I created the HT_ table manually with the displayed SQL now it always stops for the next table to create the HT_ table.

Edit: after a few times it stops again for the first table ...

Comment: It seems like it is a problem with the firebird database file itself, because another database file works fine without problems.

Comment: Try a backup and restore that backup (under a different name!), check if you see any errors during backup or restore (and if so, check the original database using gfix), and see if the freshly restored db has the same problem.

Comment: Today I updated the Firebird server and the hibernate package (with maven) and now it works without problems.
Before that I tested the 'backup and restore' method and it worked without problems. ;-)

Thanks for your help.